# how authenticate username /password of https site using php application?

Tags: php

How to check the username or password of the some https site is correct or not using PHP Application. i.e my application is www.somesite.com i want to login if the user enter valid username password of the some https site.

Regards,

Salil Gaikwad

Comment: What about `if($_GET['user'] == 'myname') { login(); }`?

Comment: Ah, if your concerns are with encryption of GET data: The URL will also be encrypted, you can safely send GET data via HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no relation between the both : 
https is a [protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https;#Difference_from_HTTP)  and to make your connection between your web server and your clients encrypted you should buy a [certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https;#Acquiring_certificates) once you did this you can authenticate your clients in the way you like and using the language you like (PHP in your case  ) because you connection is already encrypted

if you need to know about PHP authentication [check this out](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html)

Comment: sorry but i don't get what i want. Actually i don't want to authenticate username/password for my application only but also for the some other site. In my application there is a module say "XYZ" i want to show user this module only if he enter valid username/password for https://www.xyz.com  , also there is no connection between my application and  https://www.xyz.com.


Regards,

Salil Gaikwad